# Rank odds without converting

Tags: fractions

Brazil are currently playing Mexico, and at the start of the game Brazil were 2/5 to win. As it's the 38th minute and still 0-0, their odds have changed to 8/15.

Now, if I'm not wrong that represents **implied** probabilities of 71.4% and 65.2% respectively.

What I'm wondering, is whether there's an easy way of working out which odds are better without having to convert them into percentages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two fractions $\frac ab$ and $\frac cd$, you can compute $ad-bc$.  If it is greater than zero, $\frac ab \gt \frac cd$.  If it is less, $\frac ab \lt \frac cd$  You are really just putting them over a common denominator.

Comment: Perfect! Knew I was missing something simple... Slowly getting my high school maths back in my head! Thanks Ross!

Comment: So, in this example: (2x15)-(5x8) = 30 - 40 = -10 Therefore our second fraction is larger, thus implying a lower probability of winning.

Comment: Your conversion to percents implies that Brazil being $2/5$ to win means their chance to win is $5/(2+5)$.  At least that gives $71.4\%$  That is separate from comparing fractions.  It looks like you are quoting that Brazil is $5/2$ times as likely as its opponent to win.

Comment: Okay, but would it imply that the odds have indeed lengthened as the resulting -10 lets us know the second odds are greater than the first?

Comment: It tells you that $\frac 25 \lt \frac 8{15}$.  What you want to compare are $\frac 57$ and $\frac {15}{23}$ and this works fine for that, too.  If the conversion is as I think, that odds of $a/b$ means $b/(a+b)$ chance of winning, the lower odds (viewed as a fraction) are always the higher chance of winning.

Comment: It sucks that you can't mark two answers correct...

Comment: To prove that, say we are comparing quoted odds of $a/b$ and $c/d$.  We are given $ad -bc \lt 0$  As fractions we are comparing $\frac b{a+b}$ and $\frac d{c+d}$, so we compute $b(c+d)$ and $d(a+b)$ and find $bc + bd \gt ad + bd$

Answer (score 2):

Odds against of a to b is the same as a/b to 1
So 2-5 is 0.4
and 8-15 is 0.53 or just notice it is > 0.5 so it is larger than 0.4 .
Higher "odds against" implies a lower prob of winning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but if you convert them to fractions, which does not involve a calculator, you get $5/7$ and $15/23$ respectively. If you multiply $5/7$ by $3/3$, you get $15/21$, which is greater than $15/23$, and so better odds.

Answer (score 0):

Or, try a "double division": $$\frac{\frac{2}{5}}{\frac{8}{15}}=\frac{15(2)}{8(5)}=\frac{30}{40}<1 $$

Comment: Would this mean that any result greater than 1 would mean the first fraction was greater, and any result under 1 would mean the second fraction was greater?

Comment: Yes, Dan, precisely.

Comment: Great! Such a quick way of working it out!

Comment: It sucks that you can't mark two answers correct...

Comment: No problem, Dan, glad to help.